# Exporting to Excel .xlsx file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel

How can I export an .xlsx file to excel through mvc using chrome. It works for .xls but not .xlsx

```
     Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Estimate1.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Comment: take a look at http://epplus.codeplex.com/

Comment: We are using EPPlus in one of our projects and it's works great.

Comment: I'm also using it, it works great also sometimes the functions are a little bit limited, e.g. all diagram options are not available yet or it does not return an error if more than 1000000 rows are written. additionally sometimes numbers are written in a wrong way, excel then complains about broken xls files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your MIME-Types in IIS - the webserver is not aware of the Office 2007 (and higher) file extensions and refuses to serve them.

See [Register the 2007 Office system file format MIME types on servers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309278%28v=office.12%29.aspx) on TechNet on this topic.

Even if you're not using "real" IIS you should try adding the xslx MIME type to your web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xslx" mimeType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Im using a local host asp.net not IIS

Comment: @TMan Your problem sounded exactly like your webserver would know about .xls MIME-Type but miss the one for .xslx.

Comment: @Tman - as Filburt points out, your "Content type" of "application/excel" is not correct for xlsx files: you should use the one listed here - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsofficedeveloper/archive/2008/05/08/office-2007-open-xml-mime-types.aspx

Comment: Hello, I already tried using the correct mime-type, but still it says the file is corrupted

Comment: @Juran In your case, you should try to reduce to creating the most basic blank excel file and if the problem persists, try inspecting the content sent using fiddler and/or wireshark. You could also try to configure your client to open .xlsx files using notepad to inspect the content.

Comment: @Filburt i already did that, now, another error:  Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.

Comment: @Juran I'd suggest you post your problem as a new question because it will need more details than you can provide here in the comments to get at root of your specific issue. I'll check your Qs and follow up when you posted the details.